# Controlling Windows 8 using a TUIO touchscreen or Android with TUIO

Tags: windows-8, android

How can I control Windows 8 using a [TUIO](http://www.tuio.org/) multi-touch touchscreen? What about using an Android device with TUIO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate native multi-touch events...

**...using a TUIO touch screen**:

Install [EcoTUIODriver](https://github.com/ecologylab/EcoTUIODriver) by Interface Ecology Lab on your Windows 8 machine. This driver will generate Windows native touch events and it supports five monitors.

**...using an Android device**:

1. Install [TUIOdroid](http://code.google.com/p/tuiodroid/) on your Android device.
2. Install [EcoTUIODriver](https://github.com/ecologylab/EcoTUIODriver) by Interface Ecology Lab on your Windows 8 machine.